# Not able to store output from a custom function in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, logistic-regression

I have written a function to compute KS values for various iterations of a logistic regression model. When I run the code, the KS value is printed on the screen but it is not getting stored in the table.

Custom KS Function

```
def ks_value(bad_flag=None, predicted_prob=None):
    ## Data Prep
    ksdf = pd.DataFrame([])
    ksdf['bad_flag'] = bad_flag
    ksdf['probability'] = predicted_prob
    ksdf = ksdf.reset_index()
    ksdf.drop(columns=['index'],inplace=True)
    ksdf['decile'] = pd.qcut(ksdf['probability'],10,labels=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'])
    ksdf['good_flag'] = 1-ksdf['bad_flag']
    ksdf.head()

    ## Pivot
    ksdf1 = pd.pivot_table(data=ksdf,index=['decile'],values=['bad_flag','good_flag','probability'],
                         aggfunc={'bad_flag':[np.sum],
                                  'good_flag':[np.sum],
                                  'probability' : [np.min,np.max]})

    ## Add Columns
    ksdf1['total_counts'] = ksdf1['bad_flag']+ksdf1['good_flag']
    ksdf1 = ksdf1.reset_index()
    ksdf1.columns = ['Decile','Defaulter_Count','Non-Defaulter_Count','max_score','min_score','Total_Count']
    ksdf1 = ksdf1.sort_values(by='min_score',ascending=False)

    ksdf1['Default_Rate'] = (ksdf1['Defaulter_Count'] / ksdf1['Total_Count']).apply('{0:.2%}'.format)
    default_sum = ksdf1['Defaulter_Count'].sum()
    non_default_sum = ksdf1['Non-Defaulter_Count'].sum()
    ksdf1['Default %'] = (ksdf1['Defaulter_Count']/default_sum).apply('{0:.2%}'.format)
    ksdf1['Non_Default %'] = (ksdf1['Non-Defaulter_Count']/non_default_sum).apply('{0:.2%}'.format)

 ## Compute KS
    ksdf1['ks_stats'] = np.round(((ksdf1['Defaulter_Count'] / ksdf1['Defaulter_Count'].sum()).cumsum() -(ksdf1['Non-Defaulter_Count'] / ksdf1['Non-Defaulter_Count'].sum()).cumsum()), 4) * 100
    return(ksdf1['ks_stats'].max())
```

Code for iterating on Logistic Regression

```
# Iterating to find the Optimal value of C for model overfitting - Checks on Test Data

C_param_range = [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100]

table1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['C_parameter','Test Accuracy','Train Accuracy','Test KS','Train KS'])
table1['C_parameter'] = C_param_range

j = 0
for i in C_param_range:

    # Apply logistic regression model to training data
    lr = LogisticRegression(penalty = 'l2', C = i,random_state = 0,max_iter = 1000)
    lr.fit(X_train,y_train)

    # Predict class (0,1) using model
    y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
    y_pred2 = lr.predict(X_train)
    y_prob = lr.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
    y_prob2 = lr.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]

    # KS Value
    table1.iloc[j,3] = ks_value(bad_flag=y_test, predicted_prob=y_prob)
    table1.iloc[j,4] = ks_value(bad_flag=y_train, predicted_prob=y_prob2)

    # Saving accuracy score in table
    table1.iloc[j,1] = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
    table1.iloc[j,2] = accuracy_score(y_train,y_pred2)
    j += 1
```

Output is something like this: 
KS is  35.49
KS is  34.25

```
C_parameter TestAccuracy    TrainAccuracy   TestKS  TrainKS
      0.001 0.919911         0.919056        NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is the Home Credit Loan dataset available on Kaggle. Url is https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk. Filename is application_train.csv

Comment: files containing sample records of train data, target variable and predicted probability are in the given link. URL - https://safenote.co/r/5e7c8c6222ca45@34312965